# get Browser name on ConvertToXConnectInteractionProcessorBase

Tags: xconnect, processor

I'm using Sitecore 9.1.1

below processor I'm using and in this processor I'm getting value on userAgent is `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36`.

`Request.Browser.Browser` gives "Unknown" value inside this processor. I expect value for browser is Chrome here when I visit the website on chrome.

**is there any way around to get Browser name inside this custom processor?**

```
public class ConvertInteractionFacet : ConvertToXConnectInteractionProcessorBase
    {    
        public override void Process(ConvertToXConnectInteractionPipelineArgs args)
        {
            if (args != null)
            {
                string userAgent = args.XConnectInteraction.UserAgent;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: is anyone can help on this?

Comment: Does this answer help - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/4222/4515 ?